# Javascript if-statement for fixed navigation

Tags: javascript, if-statement, navigationbar

A while back I tried to figure out how to create a fixed navigation bar that smoothly animates to fit the width of the user's display. For example, my navigation bar is centered in the middle of my page and it doesn't fit the width of the webpage. What I want it to do is when the user scrolls past it, it sticks to the top of their browser and plays a nice, smooth animation that fits the width of the page.

I've accomplished to the point where it animates when the user scrolls past it, but I **also want it to play that same animation in reverse when they scroll back to the top of the page.** Currently, when the user scrolls back up, the navigation bar instantly snaps back into place without playing the animation.

I'm thinking an if-statement is required here. For example, the if-statement will check if the user has scrolled down past 218 pixels (that's what I have set for the fixed navigation bar to kick in) and if the user is, when they scroll back up it will remove the Javascript function that played the forward animation and instead play the reverse animation. My coding experience with Javascript, however, is not very good, so I was hoping I could have some help. Here is my current Javascript function that plays only the forward animation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var aboveHeight = 218;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight){
        $('sticknav').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top','60px');
        } else {
       $('sticknav').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top','0');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Surely this must be a simple feat, right? Also, the `fixed` and `sticknav` classes are ones that I created. I will have to create an `unfixed` class for when the user scrolls back to the top. `sticknav` is just a wrapper that wraps my navigation bar to tell the Javascript where to apply the `fixed` class. If you need any more information please let me know. However, **with my particular website, it doesn't seem possible that I can create a JSFiddle or anything similar.** Sorry about that.

Comment: How do you animate it? If you're using CSS transition, then set it on element for both with and without `.fixed` class. `.unfixed` will not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<header class="header black-bg">
<div class="row top-header">
    <div
        class="header-admission-name col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        Enter Your Site title</div>

</div>
<!-- Nav -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>    <span
                class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="">Menue 1</a></li>
            <li class="drpodown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown">Menue 2<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">SUB 1 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SUB 2</a></li>
                </ul></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

```
<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=(function() { 
var docElem = document.documentElement,
    didScroll = false,
    changeHeaderOn = 170;
    document.querySelector( 'header' );

function init() {
        window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
        if( !didScroll ) {
            didScroll = true;
            setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
        }
    }, false );
}   
//
function scrollPage() {
    if($("#main-content").height()>740 && $("header").height()<300)
    {   
    var sy = scrollY();
    if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
        $('.top-header').hide();
        $("header").addClass("fixed-header");
        $('.wrapper').css({ 'margin-top' : "100px"});
        $('.ad-menu').css({ 'padding-top' : 1 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 1 + "px" });
        if (/iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || $(window).width() < 479 ){
            $('.ad-menu > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 0 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 0 + "px" })
        }else{
            $('.ad-menu > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 20 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 20 + "px" })
            $('.search-side').css({ 'margin-top' : -7 + "px" });
        };
    }
    else {
        $('.top-header').slideDown(300);
        $("header").removeClass("fixed-header");
        $('.wrapper').css({ 'margin-top' : "0px"});
        $('.ad-menu').css({ 'padding-top' : 7 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 7 + "px" });

        if (/iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || $(window).width() < 479 ){
            $('.ad-menu > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 0 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 0 + "px" })
        }else{
            $('.ad-menu > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 28 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 28 + "px" })
            $('.search-side').css({ 'margin-top' : 0  + "px" });
        };

    }
    didScroll = false;
    }else{
        didScroll = false;
    }
}
    function scrollY() {
    return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
}
init();
})();
</script>
<style>
.fixed-header nav {
position: fixed;
width: 98%;
z-index: 1;
} 
</style>
```

Comment: Helpful, but I'll have to completely rework my code for this to work. I'm using a blogger template, and while this will work if I fiddle enough, it seems much too complicated... but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/surajk4437/52Lo7644/embed/"></script>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/surajk4437/52Lo7644/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=52Lo7644